# Android - Radiobutton click event to go to new activity

Tags: java, android

I would like to do something like a small selection form.

I would like to do a click event where if I select one of the first radiogroup and another one of the second it takes me to a new activity.
I got two radiogroups with two radiobuttons inside each.

```
<RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <RadioButton android:id="@+id/physic"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="physic"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>
        <RadioButton android:id="@+id/math"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="math"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>
</RadioGroup>
<RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <RadioButton android:id="@+id/theories"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="theories"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>
        <RadioButton android:id="@+id/problems_solving"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="problem solving"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>
</RadioGroup>
```

I declared my buttons and tried to use onRadioButtonClicked like below:

```
public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {
        boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

    switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.math:
            if (checked)
                switch(view.getId()) {
                    case R.id.problems_solving:
                        if (checked)
                            showFirstWord("math problem resolution");
                        break;
                    case R.id.theories:
                        if (checked)
                            showSecondWord("math theories");
                        break;
                }
            break;

        case R.id.physic:
            if (checked)
                switch(view.getId()) {
                    case R.id.problems_solving:
                        if (checked)
                            showThirdWord("physic problem solving");
                        break;
                    case R.id.theories:
                        if (checked)
                            showFourthWord("physic theories");
                        break;
                }
            break;
    }
}
```

I want the strings in the functions to appear in a text view in the other activities like below:

```
private void showFirstWord (String text) {
    Intent first_word = new Intent(this, FirstActivity.class);
    first_word.putExtra("key", text);
    startActivity(first_word);
}
private void showSecondWord (String text) {
    Intent second_word = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
    second_word.putExtra("key", text);
    startActivity(second_word);
}
private void showThirdWord (String text) {
    Intent third_word = new Intent(this, ThirdActivity.class);
    third_word.putExtra("key", text);
    startActivity(third_word);
}
private void showFourthWord (String text) {
    Intent fourth_word = new Intent(this, FourthActivity.class);
    fourth_word.putExtra("key", text);
    startActivity(fourth_word);
}
```

I tried to follow this page from Android developers but I'm still not sure what to do with it: https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/docs/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton.html

My method doesn't seem to be correct ass I can't get the strings to appear in the other activities. Is my reasonning ok for now or should I study another method?

Thanks :)

Comment: I can't know what function 1 to 4 are supposed to do. But the nested switch-case looks problematic: either the clicked View is the RadioGroup (a ViewGroup always is a View) *or* the clicked View is a RadioButton. view.getId() can't be == R.id.firstGroup and simultaneously == R.id.answer1_1. But that does not help you with the Intent question. In oder to answer this question, I'd need to see what the function... methods will do.

Comment: Sorry I tried to make what I wanted to do a little bit clearer. I hope it's a little bit more understandable. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplified your code `onRadioButtonClicked` just create first a `String` variable called `subjectSelected`.

then:

```
private String subjectSelected = "";
public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {
    RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) view;

    switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.math:
            subjectSelected = radioButton.getText().toString();
            break;
        case R.id.physic:
            subjectSelected = radioButton.getText().toString();
            break;
        case R.id.problems_solving:
            if (subjectSelected.equals("math")) {
                showFirstWord ("math problem resolution");
            } else if (subjectSelected.equals("physic")) {
                showThirdWord("physic problem solving");
            }
            break;
        case R.id.theories:
            if (subjectSelected.equals("math")) {
                showSecondWord("math theories");
            } else if (subjectSelected.equals("physic")) {
                showFourthWord("physic theories");
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

and to display the text you pass to another activity. Use a `Bundle` to get the value of your `key`.

e.g.:

```
public class FirstActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);

        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        String key = bundle.getString("key");

        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1); // Replace the textView1 with the id you set to your textview.
        textView.setText(key);
    }
}
```

***You can copy the codes of your `FirstActivity` and paste to your `SecondActivity`, `ThirdActivity` and `FourthActivity` to get the key.***

Comment: Thanks a lot! It really simplifies what I was trying to do! :) I did not think of using the string of the first answer itself!

Answer (score 0):

```
String str; // store the text corresponding to  the RadioButton which is clicked 

   switch(view.getId()) {
                case R.id.radioButton1:
                    if (checked)
                     str = "button1Text";
                    break;
                case R.id.radioButton2:
                    if (checked) 
                     str = "button2Text";
                    break;
                case R.id.radioButton3:
                    if (checked) 
                     str = "button3Text";
                    break;
         }

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, WinderDTActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("radioChosen", str); // pass "str" to the next Activity
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice I tried to implement it and it showed me a different way to make my string appear!